# How did Marion know there's a tree on the cliff?

Tags: plot-explanation, indiana-jones, the-kingdom-of-the-crystal-skull

In **[Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367882/)**, in the Amazon chasing scene, Marion was in a boat-shaped car. At the end of the chasing scene, she drives the boat-shaped car onto a tree that just happens to be growing on the side of the cliff and slips gently into the water. I guess that the tree on the cliff won't be visible from the car, because the tree was grown horizontally on the cliff.

I wonder, how did Marion definitely know there'll be a tree in the cliff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Marion sees the tree a few moments earlier.**

From the [**script** *(page 102A*)](http://www.theraider.net/films/indy4/multimedia/kingdomofthecrystalskull.pdf):

> *Marion ducks as the Russian GUNFIRE SCREECHES off the metal sides of the duck.*
>
> *But it allows Mutt and Mac to jump in from the other side, 
>   keeping low.*
>
> *Marion hits the gas and they take off toward the river. But they 
>   soon reach a short cliff.*
>
> *Marion stomps on the brakes and looks over the edge. She sees 
>   they’re only about twenty or thirty feet above the river, and 
>   there’s a large tree halfway down.*
>
> [image: Cliff] [image: Cliff]
>
> *She turns the duck around, but she’s thinking something.*